# Why MutationObserver fires many records?

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox, mutation-observers

When listen to text changes inside a contentediable **using Firefox**, for some typing, many records are fired.

For example, for the text `hello world`, if I remove character `w`, 3 records are fired, while it is 1 for other characters.

```js
let root = document.querySelector(".root")
let observer = new MutationObserver(records => {
  console.log(`records count: ${records.length}`)
  records.forEach(r => console.log(r.type))
})

observer.observe(root, {
  characterData: true,
  // characterDataOldValue: true,
  subtree: true,
  childList: true
})
```

```css
.root {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #fafafa;
  outline: 1px solid teal;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" class="root">
  <p>hello world</p>
</div>
```

Code pen: https://codepen.io/trungdo1/pen/WNjxxZr

Comment: *if I remove character w, 3 records are fired* If I remove the character w I get one update?

Comment: Oh, this happen on firefox.

Comment: Yes I can see it in firefox. Works as expected in Chrome

Comment: @Andreas thanks. I only run the example on chrome after Liam's comment.

Comment: Wow sounds like they're doing some funky stuff with contenteditables. Unfortunately, this is still quite obscure as not correctly specified yet. Not sure you can do much about it. Could you give more details about why it is an issue for you, it would probably be easier to workaround that rather than this "bug".

Comment: I am reading an open source rich text editor and I don't know why the editor's author came up with a number 3.
https://github.com/typewriter-editor/typewriter/blob/master/src/modules/input.ts#L128

Comment: Don't know either, but with their code, their `list`would only contain one item  in this case: they do keep only one instance per target node, here all three items are on the same target so only the first one would be kept in the final `list` Array. That `if (list.length > 3) return null;` is probably for yet an other case.

Comment: I know these two `3`s are not relevant. I just can not understand why the editor's author came up with a `3`, so I start learning MutationObserver. From the beginning, I do not think it is a bug but a behavior of MutationObserver, but I can not find any information about it. So I posted this question looking for help.